# Send and receive data (say text) using web sockets between angular and java

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, websocket, java-websocket

i want to establish a backend to front end connection to view real time text on UI. 
For this i want angular as front end and java as backend (not considering spring right now as i am new to socketing).

Communication should be to and fro...i.e. both ends should be receiver and sender.

i have tried using https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/socket-programming-in-java/ the client and server on geeks for geeks. It works 
Now i want my angular application to be receiver (help for making it sender would be great too)

```
import {AfterViewInit, Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
// @ts-ignore
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-server-component',
  templateUrl: './server-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./server-component.component.scss']
})
export class ServerComponentComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  private socket: any;


  public ngOnInit() {
    this.socket = io("http://localhost:5000");
  }

  public ngAfterViewInit() {  }

  public move(action: string) {
    this.socket.emit("move", action);
    console.log(action);
  }

}
```

Above logs on console but nothing is sent to backend.

when using the sender shown below:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Date;

public class Server {

  //initialize socket and input stream
  private Socket socket = null;
  private ServerSocket server = null;
  private DataInputStream in = null;

  // constructor with port
  public Server(int port) {
    // starts server and waits for a connection
    try {
      server = new ServerSocket(port);
      System.out.println("Server started");
      System.out.println("Waiting for a client ...");
      socket = server.accept();
      System.out.println("address: " + socket.getLocalPort());
      System.out.println("Client accepted");

      // takes input from the client socket
      PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

      String line = "";

      // reads message from client until "Over" is sent
      while (true) {
        try {
          System.out.println(in.readLine());
          socket.getOutputStream().write("message-backend".getBytes("UTF-8"));
        } catch (IOException i) {
          System.out.println(i);
        }
      }
      System.out.println("Closing connection");
      // close connection
      socket.close();
      in.close();
    } catch (IOException i) {
      System.out.println(i);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) { Server server = new Server(5000); }
}
```

**Below is output when server is connected but nothing happends post that:**

```
Server started
Waiting for a client ...
address: 5000
Client accepted
GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MmAFF5Q HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5000
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
Origin: http://localhost:4200
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://localhost:4200/socket
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
```

Comment: What you're trying to use is a WebSocket-based communication. But ServerSocket and all the classes nunder java.net do not provide a WebSocket-based communication. They implement plain old socket-based (not **web**-socket) communication, i.e. low-level TCP and UDP networking. You need something providing web-socket-based communication, i.e. your servlet container, or a higher-level abstraction like Spring MVC. Google for Java WebSocket.

Comment: @JBNizet your suggestion looks good but if i am able to connect to socket (see output at the end of question) then there is a connection thats been established b/w the sockets

Comment: Sure, A WebSocket communication starts with HTTP (which uses TCP) then keeps on with TCP. Do you really want to reimplement an HTTP/WebSocket server from scratch (without reading the specs)? Or would you rather reuse a tested implementation with a higher-level API?